Django is too slow when processing exception
The view where the exception happens is processing a big dictionary with about ~350K entries. The exception is a KeyError.
From what I can see from the CProfile logs, Django is trying to iterate the dictionary to get traceback data.
This is simplified code from the view:
@login_required
def export_plan_data(request):
    try:
        form = PortfolioPlanningForm(request.GET, user=request.user)
        file = get_export_file(user=request.user, form.get_params()) # This is where the exception happens

        filename = f"Plan {timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}.xlsx"
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={filename}"
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "An error occurred while exporting the data"}, status=500)

If I surround the entire view in a try/except block and return my custom response when an exception occurs it returns in about 10 seconds, but if I remove the try/except block and let Django handle the exception it takes about 5 minutes.
Here's the Cprofile dump:
         292357310 function calls (260422005 primitive calls) in 247.585 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  247.585  247.585 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py:44(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000  241.196  241.196 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py:54(response_for_exception)
        1    0.000    0.000  241.194  241.194 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py:140(handle_uncaught_exception)
        1    0.000    0.000  241.194  241.194 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/debug.py:50(technical_500_response)
        1    0.000    0.000  241.192  241.192 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/debug.py:341(get_traceback_html)
      429    0.001    0.000  241.047    0.562 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py:916(pprint)
      429    0.001    0.000  241.046    0.562 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:55(pformat)
      429    0.001    0.000  241.044    0.562 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:151(pformat)
        1    0.001    0.001  241.040  241.040 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/debug.py:269(get_traceback_data)
3228318/429   12.640    0.000  240.785    0.561 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:163(_format)
721108/16    2.370    0.000  239.680   14.980 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:189(_pprint_dict)
721108/16   11.289    0.000  239.680   14.980 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:372(_format_dict_items)
      2/1    0.002    0.001  239.667  239.667 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:446(_pprint_default_dict)
187641/61263    0.431    0.000  205.978    0.003 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:219(_pprint_list)
187647/61269    1.401    0.000  205.810    0.003 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:389(_format_items)
  6187933    9.569    0.000  158.701    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:430(_repr)
  6187933    6.127    0.000  147.533    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:439(format)
33189244/6187933   71.383    0.000  141.406    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:529(_safe_repr)
  5405048   30.852    0.000   70.697    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sorted}
  1635495   22.010    0.000   35.767    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:256(_pprint_str)
 15906637   27.737    0.000   33.766    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:99(_safe_tuple)
41216386/41216385   10.506    0.000   10.536    0.000 {built-in method builtins.repr}
  1635719    2.060    0.000    7.389    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/re.py:233(findall)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.389    6.389 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:160(_get_response)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.389    6.389 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py:18(_wrapped_view)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.373    6.373 /home/app/webapp/apps/home/views/portfolio.py:733(export_plan_data)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.358    6.358 /home/app/webapp/apps/home/views/portfolio.py:744(<lambda>)
        1    0.001    0.001    6.358    6.358 /home/app/webapp/apps/home/usecases/portfolio/export.py:129(get_export_file)
        1    0.098    0.098    6.347    6.347 /home/app/webapp/apps/home/usecases/portfolio/export.py:76(get_data_for_detail_export)
        1    0.001    0.001    6.235    6.235 /home/app/webapp/apps/home/usecases/portfolio/get_dashboard_data.py:186(get_fees_for_chart)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.224    6.224 /home/app/webapp/apps/home/usecases/portfolio/get_dashboard_data.py:60(get_dashboard_data)
        1    0.684    0.684    6.221    6.221 /home/app/webapp/apps/home/usecases/portfolio/get_dashboard_data.py:37(get_enriched_fees_from_portfolio_items)
 19596401    6.078    0.000    6.078    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:92(__lt__)
 31813274    6.028    0.000    6.028    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/pprint.py:89(__init__)
       14    0.037    0.003    5.071    0.362 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:1322(_fetch_all)
        4    0.000    0.000    5.015    1.254 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:265(__iter__)
    61235    0.115    0.000    4.969    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:97(__iter__)
       15    0.000    0.000    4.037    0.269 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/silk/sql.py:64(execute_sql)
       10    0.001    0.000    3.985    0.399 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1147(execute_sql)
        9    0.000    0.000    3.970    0.441 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1126(results_iter)
       20    0.000    0.000    3.746    0.187 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:96(execute)
       20    0.000    0.000    3.745    0.187 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:65(execute)
       20    0.000    0.000    3.745    0.187 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:71(_execute_with_wrappers)
       20    0.000    0.000    3.745    0.187 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:77(_execute)
       20    3.744    0.187    3.744    0.187 {method 'execute' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects}
  1635719    3.186    0.000    3.186    0.000 {method 'findall' of 're.Pattern' objects}
 20916708    2.776    0.000    2.776    0.000 {method 'write' of '_io.StringIO' objects}
28180497/28179681    2.571    0.000    2.590    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
  1635771    1.448    0.000    2.151    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/re.py:289(_compile)
 20109045    1.950    0.000    1.950    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
  6188513    1.599    0.000    1.599    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'dict' objects}
    82638    0.184    0.000    1.106    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py:299(loads)
  8791283    1.100    0.000    1.100    0.000 {built-in method builtins.id}
5564885/5564848    1.033    0.000    1.036    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
6242997/6242534    0.963    0.000    0.972    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
  9339835    0.917    0.000    0.917    0.000 {built-in method builtins.issubclass}
    82638    0.195    0.000    0.901    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py:332(decode)
    61239    0.123    0.000    0.764    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1115(apply_converters)
1884024/1884009    0.738    0.000    0.739    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
    61234    0.044    0.000    0.641    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/json.py:75(from_db_value)
  5405343    0.631    0.000    0.631    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
    82638    0.605    0.000    0.605    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py:343(raw_decode)
  1635522    0.426    0.000    0.426    0.000 {method 'splitlines' of 'str' objects}
  2777194    0.422    0.000    0.422    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
      426    0.257    0.001    0.257    0.001 {method 'getvalue' of '_io.StringIO' objects}
      620    0.001    0.000    0.231    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1640(cursor_iter)
      620    0.002    0.000    0.228    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1646(<lambda>)
      626    0.002    0.000    0.225    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:95(inner)
  1636531    0.223    0.000    0.223    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
      620    0.149    0.000    0.223    0.000 {method 'fetchmany' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects}
   758842    0.168    0.000    0.168    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
   455971    0.158    0.000    0.159    0.000 {built-in method builtins.next}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.127    0.127 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py:164(render)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.127    0.127 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py:161(_render)
    341/1    0.004    0.000    0.127    0.127 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py:934(render)
  6829/47    0.006    0.000    0.127    0.003 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py:897(render_annotated)
    61234    0.122    0.000    0.122    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:110(<dictcomp>)
     87/6    0.010    0.000    0.121    0.020 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py:157(render)
     2448    0.005    0.000    0.096    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py:986(render)
   312/16    0.001    0.000    0.084    0.005 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py:300(render)
   165406    0.076    0.000    0.076    0.000 {method 'match' of 're.Pattern' objects}
   122468    0.065    0.000    0.074    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_json.py:159(typecast_json)
       14    0.000    0.000    0.064    0.005 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:45(__iter__)
     2956    0.006    0.000    0.053    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py:668(resolve)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.048    0.007 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:261(__len__)
     2448    0.008    0.000    0.041    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py:963(render_value_in_context)
       25    0.001    0.000    0.038    0.002 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:503(as_sql)
   187696    0.033    0.000    0.033    0.000 {built-in method builtins.iter}
1212/1211    0.001    0.000    0.032    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py:244(inner)


That makes sense, especially if DEBUG = True, since then Django will show a traceback with the content of the variables, so it will start... well... rendering your huge blob with these 350k entries.

That makes perfect sense, especially when DEBUG is set to True. If that is the case, Django generates a page that will show the traceback, and to make it more convenient, it even adds the content of the parameters of all function calls.
This means that if your traceback somewhere thus passes your dictionary with these 350k+ entries, it will now start printing these, to add these to the response. Indeed, you can look at the error response, and expand the traceback, and then expand the variables. These are not determined when you expand the list of the variables, but Django prepares the full response.

Is there some way to disable this behavior? maybe print a sample of the function parameters? or maybe lazy load the parameters?

@Aikanáro: the simplest would probably to subclass the dictionary, and alter the __str__ method. Then thus not pass the dict as a dictionary, but as some class that has different __str__ and __repr__ behavior.
